# Advice Needed To Normalise Database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database-design, normalization

im trying to create a database for a feedback application in ASP.net i have the following database design.

```
Username (PK)

QuestionNo (PK)
QuestionText

FeedbackNo (PK)
Username

UserFeedbackNo (PK)
FeedbackNo (FK)
QuestionNo (FK)
Answer
Comment
```

a user has a unique username
a user can have multiple feedbacks

i was wondering if the database design i have here is normalised and suitable for the application

**EDIT** - a feedback has multiple questions, so there will be more than one feedback answer. hope this makes sense

**EDIT** -  i have 20 questions in the feedback form, each question can be answered by using a radio button (hence the Answer field), and optional comments can be added to each question. a user can fill out this feedback form as many times as they want. that's why i have the link table which has feedbackNo and username.

**EDIT**

```
**Users Table**
UserID (PK) autonumber
Username

**Question Table**
QuestionID (PK) autonumber
QuestionNumber
QuestionText

**Questionnaire Table**
QuestionnaireID  (PK) autonumber
UserID (FK) `User Table`
Date

**Feedback Table**
ID (PK) autonumber
QuestionnaireID (FK) `Questionnaire Table`
QuestionID (FK) `Questions Table`
Answer
Comment
```

after reading the comments ... would i have restructured my design, will this new design be suitable for my needs ?

Comment: why are the 20 feedback questions not just in the Questions table? possibly QuestionType='F'??

Comment: With your third set of edits, it looks good to me.

Comment: @ Phil, the third edit is pretty much the same as my original post, the only difference is I have added a date field in questionnaire table and i have renamed some of the field !!
@ KM, i don't fully understand what you mean

Comment: I think your original design was close to correct, as I said in my full answer.  You did correct the natural/surrogate key issue and the final table/field name ("UserFeedbackNo") in your third edit.

Comment: As far as I understand your needs, looks good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extraneous table in there.  Looks like you have a many-to-many relationship between feedbacks and users.  However, feedbacks only pertain to one user.  The cardinality should be:

- One user per feedback
- One question per feedback

Your structure should look like:

### User table

Username (PK)

### Question table

Id (PK)
QuestionText

### Feedback table

Id (PK)
UserName (FK)
QuestionId(FK)
Answer
Comment

---

With the updates c11ada provided, the design stands.  The only difference I might make in your case is that I'd store the date and time of the answer in the feedback table.

An alternative would be to create another table, the Questionnaire table, which would record an instance of feedback filled out by a user.

### Questionnaire table

Id (PK)
UserName (FK)
Date

### Feedback table

Id (PK)
QuestionnaireId (FK)
QuestionId(FK)
Answer
Comment

This is assuming the questionnaire isn't about another user.  In which case it would look like:

### Questionnaire table

Id (PK)
AboutUser (FK)
AnsweringUser (FK)
Date

Comment: I thought the same; however, if a single Feedback contains answers to several questions, the design in the question would make sense, except perhaps for the PK UserFeedbackNo, which could've been QuestionFeedbackNo. OP Might want to clarify what he's trying to accomplish in the first place.

Comment: i think i should clarify this a bit more. i have about 20 questions in my feedback form, a user can fill out this feedback form multiple times, the answers to each question needs to be stored.

Comment: +1 thanks for all the help !!can you check my final edit ... does that look right ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with something like:

```
Users
UserID         int     primary key auto number/identity
UserName       

Questions
QuestionID     int    primary key auto number/identity
QuestionNumber
QuestionText   

Feedback
FeedbackID     int    primary key auto number/identity
QuestionID     int    fk 
UserID         int    fk
Answer
Comment
```

I'd consider putting a LastChgDate and LastChgID FK column on each table, possibly even CreateDate and CreateUserID.  You will not need a special column in any of these tables to recreate the insert order, the auto number/identity values (while not always continuous are incremental) work for that.

I would avoid GUID and string keys (like Username) since they will make each index take up more memory.  I'd use a surrogate key in place of Username because it is subject to change (divorce/marriage/etc).

The Feedback table is a little troubling, is it for answers or comments? possibly should be two tables, or at least have a FeedBackType column and a single text column.  OP doesn't give enough info to fully answer this issue. Even after the OP's edit, I'm not sure I understand: `a feedback has multiple questions, so there will be more than one feedback answer`

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's usually a bad practice to have a user inputted value as a primary key. For instance, what would happen if you have to change the Username?

I personally would go with something akin to this:

```
User_ID (PK) (GUID)
UserName

Question_ID (PK) (GUID)
QuestionNumber
Question

Feedback_ID (PK) (GUID)
Question_ID (FK)
User_ID (FK)
FeedbackDate
FeedbackText
```

Furthermore, are the answers and comments independent of each other? You might consider having an answers table and a comments table.

EDIT: The FeedbackDate is for ordering purposes. It's a natural sorter compared to keeping an Order Index.

Comment: +1 for guids for PKs.  Every experience I've had with natural keys (and I've had a few) is similar to the experience that humans have once aboard an alien ship strapped to the probing table.  While easy to implement, when anything changes (data, design, etc) the shit hits the probe.

Comment: I wouldn't use a GUID though unless I needed to synchronise between inserts happening on different databases. Why not an int?

Comment: That's done more out of habit. It allows for unforeseen situations (but they never occur, right?). Say down the road, they decide to role out "MegaQuestionaire" and they want to merge in data from this source. Using GUIDs minimizes the effort involved. INTs would have a large overhead for doing this upgrade.

Comment: GUIDS are a poor choice unless you plan to replicate as they are slower than ints for joins, etc. Also I find them difficult for ad hoc querying and you often need to display the surrogate id because the text data (like the person's name) is not unique and you need it to identify the record. User's hate GUIDs because they are hard to rember and reference when there is an issue.

Planning for a data migration (and which will likely take more work anyway than simple data copying) that is unlikely to happen by harming every day performance on your system is a less than optimal choice.

Comment: Ah...the age old argument of Coke versus Pepsi. Your arguments are highly subjective and mostly it's personal preference. I will concede, that there is a slight hit on performance, but in many cases, it's a negligible issue and sometimes takes a backseat to flexibility.

Comment: guids 32 bytes vs int unsigned 4 bytes... hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edits, I think your design is correct--the feedback table represents the collection of questions/answers for a user, where the last table defines the individual answers given.  I would not include the word "User" in the last table's name/PK, as it's the Feedback table that defines user.  Call it something like "FeedbackAnswer".

Also, you are mixing surrogate keys and natural keys (Username as a key vs. FeedbackNo as a key).  This is a matter of debate as to which is better, but I'm sure more people would agree that you should stick to one approach or the other and not mix them (if possible).

Finally, if the user is to select answers from a list of possible responses, consider having an QuestionAnswer table that defines the responses for wach question, which would then relate to the FeedbackAnswer table and better normalize response data as well.

Comment: My answer was based on your 2nd edit, and did not include your third (with new table design).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is normalized.  Is Question to Feedback 1-1?  If so, make sure you have a unique constraint on the UserFeedback table that includes FeedbackNo and QuestionNo.

Comment: the feedback form consists of many questions, so Feedback to Question would be many-1 !! would my database design still hole in this situation ??

Comment: In that case, I'd go with KM's design.  That makes the most sense to me.  I don't like to have data that can change as a primary key.  It also eliminates an unnecessary table.